# Etymological analysis of swearwords

Tags: etymology, american-english, british-english, offensive-language

I'm writing a thesis about the etymological analysis of swearwords (profanity) in the English language; that is, I need to compare British and American English regarding the etymology of their swearwords. I am aware that there is a substantial amount of swearwords in both languages and I'm wondering what is the predominant source language from which swearwords evolved.

I can't seem to find any etymological analysis of swearwords online, even though many articles mention how this area is thoroughly studied. I'm quite desperate. Any suggestions on literature are most welcome. :)

Comment: Maybe ["Pardon my Anglo-Saxon"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22golfer+drove+200+yards%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22pardon+my+anglo+saxon%22&tbm=bks) isn't quite as common as ["Pardon my French"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22golfer+drove+200+yards%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22pardon+my+French%22&tbm=bks), but it's certainly more accurate.

Comment: Have you tried searching Google Scholar, or ngram searches?

Comment: On the one hand, I really want to read some interesting answers to this.  On the other hand, I have to ask, is this on topic here?

Comment: You could start by looking up the words in question in the OED and in English etymological dictionaries.

Comment: Profanity generally has a questionable etymology, so you're going to have a tough time getting a real definitive source. Even if you find a source that claims one thing, chances are you can find another source that claims something else. Good luck though.

Comment: You could also distinguish between what is taboo now and what has been taboo at previous times. Fashions change.

Comment: [etymonline.com](http://etymonline.com) has answered a few of my quesions of this subject matter.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for resources.

Answer (score 1):

There is a delightfully titled, highly learned article by Roger Lass, “Four Letters in Search of an Etymology”, Diachronica 21, 1995, pp. 99-111.

Comment: I see access is limited to purchasing a copy of the article. Can you at least share some abstract or sample content?

Comment: You say you are writing a thesis. Try your university library.

Answer (score 0):

Swearing:  A Social History of Foul Language, Oaths, and Profanity in English by Geoffrey Hughes

It's a pretty good source of information.

[Here is a link to it on Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140267077)